# Angular 1/$interpolate - interpolate elements in array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-interpolate

I have this array `stateData.submenu` :

```
[
  {
    "template": "<span>myContacts</span>",
    "sref": "contact.list"
  },
  {
    "template": "<span>myProjects</span>",
    "sref": "project.list"
  },
  {
    "template": "<span>myRecommendations</span>
      <span class=\"badge\">{{ notificationBadge }}</span>",
    "sref": "recommendation.list"
  }
]
```

For `$interpolate` the `template` property in the third element of the array I do (to interpret the `{{ notificationBadge }}` expression) :

```
this.interpolateTemplate = this.$interpolate(stateData.submenu[2].template)(this)
```

but it's not very clean, I would like to create a loop that iterate on all the `template` properties of the array and the `$interpolate`.

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said you can iterate your templates and then $interpolate, like so.

```
var self = this;
this.notificationBadge = "Just a test"
this.templates = [{
     "template": "<span>myContacts</span>",
     "sref": "contact.list"
   },{
     "template": "<span>myProjects</span>",
     "sref": "project.list"
   },{
     "template": "<span>myRecommendations</span> < span class=\"badge\">{{ notificationBadge }}</span>",
     "sref": "recommendation.list"
   }].map(function each(template){
        template.template = $interpolate(template.template)(self)
        return template;
    })
```